# How to handle serialization exception with kafka stream

Tags: exception, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm currently struggling handling serialization exceptions properly in a kafka stream application. Using the latest version. Exception handling for deserialization and production exceptions are fine. There I'm using

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, MyCustomDeserializationExceptionHandler.class);
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_PRODUCTION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, MyCustomProductionExceptionHandler.class);
```

I'm using AVRO as output format and having define such a serde:

```
private SpecificAvroSerde<MyClass> avroSerde(Properties envProps) {
  SpecificAvroSerde<MyClass> avroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
  final HashMap<String, String> serdeConfig = new HashMap<>();
  serdeConfig.put(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, envProps.getProperty("schema.registry.url"));
  avroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
  return avroSerde;
}
```

If for example a required value is not set we obviously get an exception. But as we are dynamically mapping input values it's not really in our hand if we get correct values. An exception looks like

```
Error encountered sending record to topic NAME for task 0_0 due to:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Error encountered sending record to topic NAME for task 0_0 due to:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
    at 
org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:167)
    at 
org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:91)
```

Finally the question/problem. How can I handle such serialization exceptions properly? I would like to log the error and not having the stream failing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see MyCustomDeserializationExceptionHandler as part of the stacktrace, so are you sure that's working?

Comment: @OneCricketeer That's correct you do not see the deserialization exception but is for the reason that it is not a deserialization rather than a serialization exception. The exception occurs during the "sending"/producing.

Comment: Oh, you're right... Is there more to the stacktrace? And what do you mean by "required value not set"? Surely you can check for this somewhere before starting the topology

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm using an AVRO schema. With that I meant if the serialization fails due to a value is not set but it should as the AVRO field is not accepting null values.

Comment: The data format is irrelevant to the exception handling... AFAIK, Kafka Streams cannot put a serialization exception handler in the config because each node of the topology has the ability to use a different serializer. The only way you'd be able to catch an exception in any specific step would be to produce using the BytesSerde, then use a map function (or the processor api) to attempt deserialization, catching the exception, then not forwarding those messages

Comment: @bluepix Did you get any solution? I am facing similar issue.

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for your feedback. Will try to do something in this direction

Comment: @ani0710 Unfortunately not. Somehow still hoping there would be a nice way to do it